# How to fix this? I don't know the name

Tags: php

So, I am working with php again, and I have a problem. I have 2 different variables with arrays. And I want the 2 variables to come in a foreach().

Here is my code:

```html
<?php
$var['1'] = '1';
$var1['1'] = '1';
$var['2'] = '2';
$var1['2'] = '2';
foreach ($var, $var1 as $value, $value1) {
    echo $value . "<br>";
    echo $value1 . "<br>";
}
?>
```

How can I do this? How can I make this work?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Are you just trying to iterate through both arrays in one loop? Would it work to set an index variable, and then just save `var[i]` and `var1[i]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not iterate through two arrays in one loop at once.

But the `next()` function may help you in this case

The official example about next:

```
<?php
$people = array("Peter", "Joe", "Glenn", "Cleveland");

echo current($people) . "<br>";
echo next($people);
?>
```

Iterate through the first array and use the `next()` function to get the value of the other array.

```
<?php
$var['1'] = '1';
$var1['1'] = '1';
$var['2'] = '2';
$var1['2'] = '2';
foreach ($var as $value) {
    echo $value . "<br>";

    $value1 = current($var1);
    echo $value1 . "<br>";

    next($var1);
}
?>
```

Comment: No, I really need like those 2 variables from each other.

Comment: @Aaronjonk Try my snippet

Comment: it works, thnx!